# Maximum current through an LED

Tags: voltage, led, power, current, led-driver

I have [these LEDs](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00XBS2EZC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for which the max current was not specified. However I know that the voltage is 3.2V-3.6V and the power is 1W.
Is it correct to assume that the maximum current is therefore 0.27A ?

i=p/u=1W/3.6V

Comment: 350 mA seems resonable.

Comment: When it doesnt come with a proper datasheet, how can you trust anything the seller claims? There is a reason why people recommend to never buy without a datasheet. I personally doubt they are 1W

Comment: **cardinal rule:**  *No datasheet ⇒ No sale*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you say is true, then yes. A typical 1 Watt led will take 300 mA or so depending on the forward voltage. Heatsink it properly though.

Comment: What would be the surface for such an LED?

Comment: Surface? Maximum? Over driving them to 350 mA at 3.5 V **at most** otherwise you risk blowing it much early. Under drive them at 300 for best life. A constant current supply is recommended.

Comment: @SolarWind: Surface of 1W dice is typically 1 mm².

Comment: @Ariser-you mean centimeter?